# powershell searching for a phrase in a large amount of files fast

Tags: powershell, search

Hello my question is is there a faster way to search for a phrase in a file other than select-string. I need to find a certain phrase in the first line of about 60k files but the current way i am doing it is too slow for what i need to have done.
I have tried doing

```
(Select-String "Phrase I am looking for" (cat mylist1)).Filename > mylist2
```

which gave me a result of 2 minutes and 30 seconds and then i tried

```
cat mylist1| %{ if ((cat $_ -first 1) -match "Phrase I am looking for") {echo $_}} > mylist2
```

which gave me a result of 2 minute and 57 seconds. Is there another method of searching for a string through a large amount of files that can bring the search time down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have at least PowerShell 3.0 then you could use `.Where` with `Get-Content`'s `-TotalCount` and that should help some. `-TotalCount` defines how many lines of the file are being read in. I see that you are already using its alias `-First` though so there won't be any big changes here for that.

```
$path = "d:\temp"
$matchingPattern = "function"
(Get-ChildItem $path -File).Where{(Get-Content $_ -TotalCount 1) -match $matchingPattern }
```

I will try and test this against 60K of files and see what I can get in the mean htim. The above would return file objects where the first line contains "function". My test ran against 60K of files but my lines were likely shorter. Still did it in 44 seconds so perhaps that will help you

StreamReader will usually beat out `Get-Content` as well but since we are only getting one line I don't think it will be more efficient. This uses a streamreader in the where clause and reads the first line.

```
(Get-ChildItem $path -File).Where{([System.IO.File]::OpenText($_.Fullname).ReadLine()) -match $matchingPattern }
```

Note that the above code could contain a memory leak but it finished in 8 seconds compared to my first test. Writing to file added a second or two. Your mileage will vary.

Note that `-match` supports regex so you would need to escape regex meta characters if present.

Comment: just tried it on what i have, maybe should have specified the pattern i am looking for is in multiple files. Anyway just tested both and without the writes they give me 2mins 13 secs and 4mins 42 seconds

Comment: Was the 4 minutes on the stream reader? Can you reduce the selection set of files at all?

Comment: Also I figured multiple files were being returned. How are you measuring execution time?

Comment: The 4 minutes was the stream reader. No i can't reduce the selection set of the files as they all have nothing in the file name that can differentiate them from. Also measuring execution time with measure-command{"code"}

Comment: I wonder if we can also improve what you are searching for? Do you have an example of a phrase you are actually looking for? If its not regex then perhaps `.Contains()` will be faster. Will need to test will larger data sets then.

Comment: The phrase i am searching for is "MAIN_HDR:322:ABCDEFG:$($someCode)" no regex needed

Answer (score 1):

You can do simply it:

```
$yoursearch = "PowerShell is cool!"
get-content "c:\temp\*.*" -TotalCount 1 | where { $_ -ilike "*$yoursearch*"} | select PSPath, @{N="Founded";E={$_}}
```

or A short version for non-purists:

```
gc "c:\temp\*.*" -To 1 | ? { $_ -ilike "*$yoursearch*"} | select PSPath, {$_}
```

If you want export your result:

```
$yoursearch = "PowerShell is cool!"
get-content "c:\temp\*.*" -TotalCount 1 | where { $_ -ilike "*$yoursearch*"} | select PSPath, @{N="Founded";E={$_}} |
export-csv "c:\temp\yourresult.csv" -notype
```

If you want a better filter for files input :

```
Get-ChildItem "c:\temp" -File | 
    Where {$firstrow= (Get-Content $_.FullName -TotalCount 1); $firstrow -ilike "*$yoursearch*"} | 
         Select fullName, @{N="Founded";E={$firstrow}} |
              Export-Csv "c:\temp\yourresult.csv" -notype
```

or A short version for non-purists:

```
gci "c:\temp" -File | ? {$r= (gc $_.FullName -TotalCount 1); $r -ilike "*$yoursearch*"} | 
    Select f*, @{N="Founded";E={$r}} |
        epcsv "c:\temp\yourresult.csv" -notype
```

Note: -file option exist only in PowerShell V5 (or +), else use psiscontainer propertie into where instruction

Note2: You can use option -list of select-string, seach all in file but stop when 1 row is founded

```
$yoursearch = "PowerShell where are you"
Select-String  -Path "c:\temp\*.*" -Pattern $yoursearch -list | select Path, Line | export-csv "C:\temp\result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to write to a file is to use the StreamWriter object. Assuming the files are in a folder:

```
$writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "selection.txt"
$files = gci -Path $path 
$pattern ="Phrase"
$files | %{gc -Path $_.FullName | select -First 1 | ?{$_ -match $pattern}} | %{$writer.WriteLine($_)}
```

Comment: I don't think writing is the problem. Also you would make it worse since your code is reading in the more than one line of the file even with the optimization of select in newer versions

Comment: So how would you be finding the line with that phrase and write it to a file through your code snippet?

Comment: Mine is missing set-content and anyone can add that but I think the reading performance is the issue was my point.

Answer (score 0):

An example on how I would do it would be something like

Get-ChildItem -Path $path | Where-Object{$_.Name -contains "My String"}

This is generally a pretty fast way of achieving this however be advised if you -recurse through the entire C:\ drive then regardless you will be sitting for a minute unless you multi-thread