# Using Powershell runspaces to search large number of files (.XML)

Tags: powershell, search, get-childitem, runspace, select-string

I have a script that will look for a regex inside a large number of files, such as an address or phonenumber. The script i currently have runs as a job and works, however very slowly.

Currently my method of start-job works as expected, all be it slowly. Im looking for ways to speed up and returning results quicker. If at all possible

I have ventured into the world of Runspaces within powershell after browsing around for various help. Below is the code i have mashed together with brief understanding in the use of Runspaces.

My question is around the way that Runspaces can be used so that a Get-Childitem request running in parallel will not be scanning the same file across multiple runspaces. If this is even possible?

I created 20,000 files containing junk, and manually edited 2 files with the word "KETCHUP!" inside.

10k files are .xml
10k files are .txt

Im trying not to use PS v7 -parallel parameters as i would like to hand my script/GUI to other members of staff that are not in IT and will not have higher than ISE installed

[powershell searching for a phrase in a large amount of files fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41309376/powershell-searching-for-a-phrase-in-a-large-amount-of-files-fast)

```
$Finished.text = 'Working.....' 

#Get list of files to search through
$path = "C:\intel\spam"
Push-Location $path
$FILES = Get-ChildItem -filter *.XML -File

### 5 Runspace limit
$RunspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,5)
$RunspacePool.ApartmentState = "MTA"
$RunspacePool.Open()
$runspaces = @()

# Setup scriptblock
$scriptblock = {
   Param (
    [object]$files
   )
    foreach($file in $files){
  $test = select-string  -Path $file -Pattern 'KETCHUP!' -List | select-object FileName,Path
  
  if($test)
{
add-content -Path 'C:\intel\matches.txt' -Value $test.Filename
}
    }
                }


Write-Output "Starting search..."

       $runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
       [void]$runspace.AddScript($scriptblock)
       [void]$runspace.AddArgument($FILES) # <-- Send files to be searched
       $runspace.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool

    $AsyncObject = $runspace.BeginInvoke() 

# Wait for runspaces to complete
while ($runspaces.Status.IsCompleted -notcontains $true) {}

# Cleanup runspaces 
foreach ($runspace in $runspaces ) { 
    $runspace.Pipe.EndInvoke($runspace.Status) 
    $runspace.Pipe.Dispose()
}

# Cleanup runspace pool
$RunspacePool.Close() 
$RunspacePool.Dispose()


  $Data = $runspace.EndInvoke($AsyncObject)

Pop-Location
```

Comment: `get-childitem . *.xml | foreach-object -parallel { select-string pattern $_ }`

Comment: Thank you, however I’m looking to use ps v5 and thus -parralel is not available

Comment: You can install the Threadjob module and use `start-threadjobs { '...' } | receive-job -wait -auto`

Comment: Thanks @js2010 , but I’m looking to keep this script as natural as possible. This helps compatability with additional users without the need for extra add Ons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is around the way that Runspaces can be used so that a
> Get-Childitem request running in parallel will not be scanning the
> same file across multiple runspaces. If this is even possible?

It really comes down to logic, and that would be in breaking the files to search for in chunks - *which is totally doable*. The way it works is more or less like this. Let's imagine you have **8** files and a hypothetical **2**-*core CPU*:

```
[File1] [File2] [File3] [File4] [File5] [File6] [File7] [File8]     <- All files from Get-ChildItem
```

After determining the *chunk_size* (which would be **4** in this hypothetical scenario since **8** files divided by **2** cores is **4**), the code would divide these files into chunks:

```
Chunk 1: [File1] [File2] [File3] [File4]
Chunk 2: [File5] [File6] [File7] [File8]
```

This division would be stored in the `$file_chunks` *ArrayList*:

```
$file_chunks:
Index 0: [File1] [File2] [File3] [File4]
Index 1: [File5] [File6] [File7] [File8]
```

Now, when parallel processing begins, each CPU core (or runspace) picks up a chunk:

```
CPU Core 1 (Runspace 1): Processing [File1] [File2] [File3] [File4]
CPU Core 2 (Runspace 2): Processing [File5] [File6] [File7] [File8]
```

Each core works on its own subset of files, allowing for faster parallel processing.

With this said and done, you can create a more robust solution such as a function to re-use it in a more friendly manner:)

```
function Search-Files {
    Param(
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Path,

        [Parameter()]
        [string[]]$Filter = @('*.txt', '*.xml'),

        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Pattern,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch]$Recurse
    )

    $regex = [regex]::new($pattern, [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Compiled)
    $file_list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()

    $searchOption = if ($Recurse) { [System.IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories } else { [System.IO.SearchOption]::TopDirectoryOnly }
    foreach ($find in $Filter) 
    {
        try 
        {
            $file_list.AddRange([System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($Path, $find, $searchOption))
        } 
        catch 
        {
            Write-Warning "An error occurred while fetching files with filter ${find}: $_"
        }
    }


    $file_count = $file_list.Count
    $cpu_count = [Environment]::ProcessorCount
    $optimal_runspaces = [Math]::Min($cpu_count, $file_count)
    $file_chunks = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string[]]]::new($optimal_runspaces)

    $runspace_pool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $optimal_runspaces)
    $runspace_pool.Open()

    $chunk_size = [Math]::Ceiling($file_count / $optimal_runspaces)
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $optimal_runspaces; $i++) 
    {
        $start = $i * $chunk_size
        $end   = [Math]::Min(($start + $chunk_size - 1), ($file_count - 1))

        $file_chunks.Add($file_list[$start..$end])
    }

    $scriptblock = {
        Param($files, $regex)

        $results = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
        foreach ($file in $files) 
        {
            try 
            {
                $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($file)
                while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) 
                {
                    $line = $reader.ReadLine()
                    if ($regex.IsMatch($line)) 
                    {
                        $results.Add($file)
                        break
                    }
                }
            } 
            finally 
            {
                if ($reader) 
                {
                    $reader.Dispose()
                }
            }
        }
        return $results
    }

    $runspaces = @{}
    foreach ($chunk in $file_chunks) 
    {
        $runspace = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($scriptblock).AddArgument($chunk).AddArgument($regex)
        $runspace.RunspacePool = $runspace_pool
        $runspaces[$runspace] = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
    }

    # Wait for all runspaces to complete
    while ($runspaces.Values | Where-Object { -not $_.IsCompleted }) 
    {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    }

    $all_results = foreach ($runspace in $runspaces.GetEnumerator()) 
    {
        $runspace.Key.EndInvoke($runspace.Value)
    }

    $runspace_pool.Close()
    $runspace_pool.Dispose()

    # Flatten the results for a single list of matched file paths
    return $all_results
}

# Usage
$path = "C:\intel\spam"
$filter = "*.xml"
$pattern = "KETCHUP!"
$results = Search-Files -Path $path -Filter $filter -Pattern $pattern

$results | ForEach-Object { Add-Content -Path 'C:\intel\matches.txt' -Value $_ }
```

---

Comment: you have increased my PS knowledge and understanding by a huge about in this post, Many light bulbs have now turned on! :D

Thank you so much for this!